# AES encrypted variable doesn't get inserted PHP - Mysqli Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security, encryption

I have a variable which has to be encrypted and after that saved to the database via mysqli prepared statement. I use AES-256-CTR.

```
$tabvar = openssl_encrypt($final, $encryptionMethod, $secret, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
```

After the encryption the result looks like this: **5œœ¼Ç=áüû;€é?**

This is my php insert code:

```
$ins = mysqli_prepare($db, "INSERT INTO tab (tid, tabvar) VALUES (?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($ins, "ss",$tid,$tabvar); mysqli_stmt_execute($ins);
```

Because the $tabvar consist of some very strange characters once encrypted, it doesn't get inserted in the database. If I change $tabvar to "i" the row get's inserted, but the entry under tabvar column is 0?

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: That's because `openssl_encrypt()` with `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` returns a binary string.

Comment: I changed it to "b" and the column to longblob, but it's still empty..

Comment: Just encode it with `base64_encode($tabvar)` and store it as an ordinary string?

Comment: I would need a better encryption than base64_encode.. That's why I am using the above-mentioned solution.

Comment: But the question remains why is the entry row empty on tabvar column.. I have tried varbinary now and it's the same. Could be the lenght issue?

Comment: I meant that you could encode the binary result from `openssl_encrypt()` with base64... or convert it with `bin2hex($tabvar)`. I didn't mean that you should use it instead... :)

Comment: Sofar it get's inserted into the DB as well as restored and decrypted.. Will report if anything is malfunctioning. Thanks.. You were really helpful :)